# Awk - addition and division in a multi column file

Tags: awk

I have an input file like -

```
ABC 1 2  
DEF 3 4  
ABC 4 8    
DEF 7 1
```

Expected output is to group the first column and add the values in columns 2 and 3. Then divide values in columns 2 and 3 and store the result in column 4.

```
ABC 5 10 0.5   
DEF 10 5 2
```

Your tips will be great appreciated.

Comment: Have you started on a solution for this that you got stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{r[$1]+=$2;R[$1]+=$3}END{for(i in r){print i" "r[i]" "R[i]" "r[i]/R[i]}}'
```

Reads as:

- For every line, store the first column `$1` as index in `r`, and the accumulated (`+=`) sum of column `$2` as value in `r`, and do likewise for column `$3` in `R`.
- When all lines have been read (`END`), print for each `$1`-group `i`, the sum of `$2` (`r[i]`), the sum of `$3` (`R[i]`), and finally the ratio of `∑($2)` to `∑($3)`.